# How do I determine if a user is still logged in to FireBase on app launch using Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

When app launches I want to check if the user is logged in or not and based on that I want to either show the `login/signup` page or the `homepage`. From the documentation, I know that once a user logs in his or her session persists and there is no sense in asking the user to login every time

> The Firebase SDKs for all platforms provide out of the box support for
> ensuring that your user's authentication state is persisted across app
> restarts or page reloads.
>
> On native platforms such as Android & iOS, this behavior is not
> configurable and the user's authentication state will be persisted
> on-device between app restarts. The user can clear the apps cached
> data via the device settings which will wipe any existing state being
> stored.

I'm trying to achieve the above using the below code attempt:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  // to check if we're already logged in or not
  User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

  @override
  void initState() {
    print(user);
    print(user!.email);
    if (user != null){
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text('${user!.email} signed in'),
        ),
      );
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()),
      );
    }
    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.verified_user, size: 98,),
            SizedBox(height: 5,),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignInScreen()),
                );
              },
              child: Text('LOGIN'),
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                shape: StadiumBorder(),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 5,),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignUpScreen()),
                );
              },
              child: Text('SIGN UP'),
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                shape: StadiumBorder(),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

That is at `init` it should check for the user and if its not null then push to the `homepage`. But I get the error:

> dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_ScaffoldMessengerScope>() or
> dependOnInheritedElement() was called before
> _MyHomePageState.initState() completed.

This makes sense I guess, as I am trying to make use of the `Scaffold` before its even loaded. Given all this, how do I show homepage/login page after checking for user login at app launch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to have a StreamBuilder as high in the widget tree as possible, for example right inside runApp.
It will listen to any of userChanges and rebuild the content accordingly.

Simplified code snippet below:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp().then((value) {
    print('firebase initialized');
  }).catchError((err) => print(err));

  runApp(GetLandingPage());
}


class GetLandingPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const GetLandingPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<User?>(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.userChanges(),
      initialData: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<User?> snapshot) {
        // Check if user is logged in
        final String? uid = snapshot.data?.uid;

        if (uid != null)
          return HomePage();

        return LoginPage();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move your logic to didChangeDependencies.

This method will be called multiple times so put a flag to check it one time only.

Use ScaffoldKey as well as context you will recieve in didChangeDependencies will be unaware of Scaffold.

Answer (score 1):

You can update your `initState` to call the methods in the callback of `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback`.

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    print(user);
    print(user!.email);
    if (user != null){
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text('${user!.email} signed in'),
        ),
      );
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()),
      );
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check for previous authentication in main, and then set your home/initial route based on that check. This is what I've been using and it's worked well for me so far:

```
void main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      runApp(MyApp());      
}
    
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  //use this bool to determine which page to navigate to on app load
  bool loggedInUser;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    //before loading the page, check if a user previously logged in
    getCurrentUser();
  }

  void getCurrentUser() {

    //check to see if the user is logged into firebase from a previous session
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

    //if the user is logged in, go to the profile page
    if (user != null) {
      loggedInUser = true;
    }
    //otherwise the user is not logged in, and we need them to authenticate
    else {
      loggedInUser = false;
    }
  }

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      initialRoute: loggedInUser ? HomeScreen.id : LoginScreen.id,
      routes: {
        LoginScreen.id: (context) => LoginScreen(),
        HomeScreen.id: (context) => HomeScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Once you're in your HomeScreen, you could show the Scaffold alerting the user to successful authentication there.